# Finding the minimum and maximum value of P(A and B)

Tags: probability, self-study

I have this homework question that I can't seem to solve a part of it.

The Question is:

> Suppose your right knee is sore 15% of the time, and your left knee is sore 10% of the time. What is the largest possible percentage of time that at least one of your knees is sore? What is the smallest possible percentage of time that at least one of your knees is sore?

Here's what I have so far:

> Let $A$ be the event that the right knee is sore and  $P(A) = 0.15$. Let $B$ be the event that the left knee is sore and $P(B) = 0.10$.
>
> $\max{P(A \text{ or } B)} = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and }B)$
>
> The maximum value is obtained when $P(A \text{ and }B)$ is 0, and the maximum value is $0.15+0.1 = 0.25$
>
> $\min{P(A \text{ or }B)} = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and }B)$.

Now I don't know how to find the max value of $P(A \text{ and }B)$ to calculate the minimum of $P(A \text{ or }B)$.

Comment: @Silverfish Finished all the edits, i'll keep these in mind for the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $P(A \text{ or } B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and }B)$ is always true.

Since $P(A)=0.15$ and $P(B)=0.10$, the maximum value of $P(A\text{ or }B)$ is obtained if $P(A \text{ and }B)$ is at its minimum possible value which is $0$. $P(A\text{ and }B)=0$ means there is no overlap between $A$ and $B$ (the left knee and the right knee will never be sore at the same time).

Similarly, the minimum possible value of $P(A\text{ or }B)$ is obtained if $P(A \text{ and }B)$ is at its maximum possible value. Since $P(A \text{ and }B)$ is always smaller than or equal to either $P(A)$ or $P(B)$, its maximum is $\min\{P(A), P(B)\}=\min\{0.15, 0.1\}=0.1$. In this case, $(A\text{ and }B)=B$ which means when your left knee is sore, you right know must also be sore.

In summary, the maximum value of $P(A\text{ or }B)$ is $0.25$ and the minimum value is $0.15$.